# Android: Actionbar Sherlock error in the library project

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I followed these steps and did exactly the same:

http://www.slideshare.net/androidstream/action-bar-sherlock-tutorial

But the problem is this `com_actionbarsherlock` has many errors in its src folder files.

most(or don't know if all) of the errors are like this:

```
The method onPreparePanel(int, View, Menu) of type _ActionBarSherlockTrojanHorse must override a superclass method
```

Library Manifest has this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.actionbarsherlock"
    android:versionCode="90"
    android:versionName="4.1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

</manifest>
```

and project build target is API 14

and my project manifest has this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.sherlock"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
        <activity
            android:name=".SherlockActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and project build target is API 10

How to solve this??

Thank you

Comment: should i remove @override for all such errors?? there are like 15-20 such errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting myself from [a blog post from this week](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/14/about-those-override-errors.html):

> There are two ways to fix this.
>
> For an individual project, you can go into Project > Properties, choose the “Java Compiler” category on the left, and change the value in the “Compiler compliance level” drop-down. Sometimes, this will be disabled, because you are using your workspace-level setting and are not overriding it at the project level. Sometimes, though, the project might be set to override it at the project level and have it set to 1.5. If you would prefer to not override it on a project where it is overridden, you can uncheck the “Enable Project Specific Settings” checkbox at the top of the dialog.
>
> For your entire workspace, you can go to the Preferences window and choose Java > Compiler from the category tree on the left. Here, you will see another “Compiler compliance level” drop-down, one that controls the default for all of your projects.
>
> Maintaining a consistent 1.6 compiler compliance level will clear up these @Override complaints.

Comment: by changing the Compiler compliance level from 1.5 to 1.6 solved my problem. Thanks a lot. But when i want this library to be used in a project, when i click add button in the library panel of the project i can't see this library. I can see my facebook library but not this

Comment: @Archie.bpgc: Project > Properties > Android, check the "Is a Library" checkbox.

Comment: and i have the project build target = API 10

Comment: and this in my manifest: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

Comment: @Archie.bpgc: Then check the checkbox, so say that ActionBarSherlock *is a library*.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc: I don't know what to tell you, other than to try restarting Eclipse. Simply having that checkbox be checked is sufficient to have it show up in the "Add..." list dialog in another project, AFAIK.

Comment: yeah i even tried that. But are you sure this is not the problem caused by the values at minSDK, Target API etc??

Comment: @Archie.bpgc: Ah -- set your build target to 14 or higher. ActionBarSherlock needs a build target of 14 or higher, and when you use a library project, your app needs the same (or higher) build target than any of its libraries.

Comment: okay i thing i observed is. when i click on someother project and click add button of the library panel it shows facebookLibrary and my project(not the actionbarSherlock library). had i done something wrong?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc: Libraries (e.g., ActionBarSherlock) need "Is a Library" checked. You can tell that because **that is what the checkbox says**. My guess is that you checked it for your project and did not check it for ActionBarSherlock. And you will need your project build target to be API Level 14 or higher.